# Are the speakers in this video speaking standard American English?

Tags: american-english, accent

I want to improve my American English accent, and I found [Learn Real English](http://learnrealenglish.com/), which is quite interesting to me. Anyway, I don't know much about standard American accent, so I want to know if those teachers (links below) speak standard American or not.

[Video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KazofT_jtHA)
[Video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PipEJYoT0dg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that they are definitely speaking with a generic American accent. Many US English speakers would characterize those two people as having no accent at all, and they certainly don't have any obvious regional accent.

As to standard American constructions and figures of speech, they are probably more formal than you'd typically find, but again there's no doubt that any US English speaker would recognize their speech as regionally neutral.

Comment: If I close my eyes and listen to her, I imagine she's from the SF Bay Area - that could just be me, though.

Answer (score 2):

I listened only briefly to those videos, but their accents are very much unmarked standard American accents, without any obvious regional markers.

Answer (score 2):

As a Canadian, I would say they are both speaking with a [General American](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American) accent. I agree with the other answers that most Americans (and indeed most Canadians) would say they "don't have an accent."

I'm not an expert on dialect or accents, but I have a couple more points. I can tell if I listen very closely that they are American (and not Canadian) — I still maintain that we don't say aboot but I can tell the slight difference in your abawts. ;-)

If I were to guess where they grew up — and these are really wild guesses from a Canadian steeped in American TV — the woman sounds to my ear to be very slightly southern in her speech, possibly Midland American. The man sounds west-coastish to me for some reason I can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: Very nice ears, Canadian. ;)

Comment: Yes, Americans do have accents. My native language is Italian, but I have spent most of my life in the US. Whenever I visit Italy, I am often told that I speak Italian with an American accent. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The woman states that she is originally from Georgia. While many Georgians have distinct southern accents, she lacks one. The man has a similarly indistinct American accent. I am from Virginia, and I interact with people who have very similar accents and speech habits/mannerisms every day.

Comment: I'm not good in English, do you mean they both speak generic American accent?

Comment: Yes, they speak with a generic American accent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there really isn't such a thing as the "Standard American Accent."  There are many regional accents throughout the United States, and each of them is equally valid.  Most regional accents can be easily understood by most Americans, so I wouldn't worry too much about learning the so-called "Standard American" accent perfectly.

I was born and raised in Erie, Pennsylvania.  The dialect in my part of the country is classified as Midland Standard American.  We speak the so-called "Standard American" accent used on national television broadcast stations -- the accent that is supposed to be without any recognizable regional markers.  I have no idea who decided that our specific dialect should be the so-called "Standard American" accent, but it is.  I mention this because when I listened to the lady in Video 1, it was fairly easy to compare her accent to my own.

She is definitely speaking standard American English.  Her accent is very similar to my own with only very subtle differences which are hardly noticeable.  However, she is being very careful and deliberate in her pronunciation, so I believe this accent was learned, and is not her own native accent.  The fact that she said she is originally from Georgia would support this observation, since the beautiful Southern American dialect spoken in Georgia is quite different from my own.

However, if one were to learn to speak with the same accent she is using in the video, most Americans would certainly consider it to be quite standard American speech.

I hope this helps!